# NYC Istanbul, generate report with testcase name

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

When I generate a coverage report using nyc it always give coverage results of the file(how much percentage is been covered). Although is there any way to figure out, which testcase name has contribute to the coverage of that file ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it is possible to see the tests that hit the lines of the code or that provide coverage for a specific file. Nyc can be integrated with different coverage tools like codecov en coveralls, but in this tools I haven't found an option for this.

I don't know what you want with the option to view the test names for the different files. But for debugging purposes there is also an visual studio code extension for mocha that let's you debug your tests (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maty.vscode-mocha-sidebar).